# Accessing NASDAQ Historical Data with Python Requests Results in Connection Timeout

Tags: python, python-requests, finance

I tried to run this snippet of Python code (with the requests library) to retrieve a year's worth of Tesla's historical market data from NASDAQ.com

```
dataURL = https://www.nasdaq.com/api/v1/historical/TSLA/stocks/2019-05-22/2020-05-21
quotesReq = requests.get(dataURL, allow_redirects = True)
```

Despite being able to access the URL through a web browser and downloading the intended ".csv" file, my Python code produces a timeout error.

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None))
```

Is this because NASDAQ.com has anti-scraping measures in place, or am I missing some information in my request? Any help fixing the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably because the site has anti-scraping measures.  Scraping a website is seen as a faux-pas anyway, even if they don't provide an API for you to get the data you want.

Comment: Try setting user-agent for your request header as some browser and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Makoto I rearranged the rest of my code a bit, and now get "ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host", which seems to be the cause of the timeout error in the first place. Do you have a suggestion for getting around this?

Comment: @noobius it unfortunately did not make a difference with the following headers:     headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8 GTB7.1 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)", "Referer": "http://example.com"}

Comment: Have you look into Selenium webdriver?  Using something like selenium chrome driver might work.  That's where I would go next.  But check with the provider to understand their terms for scraping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution with using Selenium chromedriver.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

dataURL = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/api/v1/historical/TSLA/stocks/2019-05-22/2020-05-21'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe')  
driver.get(dataURL)
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Again, check with the provider for terms on proper scraping.  You can look into more of selenium chromewebdriver, https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started

Answer (score 9):

Try by adding these three headers:

```
"Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.9"
"Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br"
"User-Agent":"Java-http-client/"
```

Comment: That works ideally.