# NASDAQ PULL DATA

Tags: curl, beautifulsoup, python-requests, scrape, stock

I have a list of 500 indices. I am trying to just pull the corresponding name of the company for each index. I am using a simply request for each item:

```
url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/markey-activity/stocks/{}'.format('CCL')
r = requests.get(url)
```

This request keeps running and doesn't return anything.

I also tried a simple `curl {url}' which doesn't return anything in terminal either.

Is this something specific with NASDAQ?

Comment: you misspelled market in the url, try this 
`url="https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/tsla"`

Comment: I actually spelled it correctly in the original request (just not my post). I also tried just doing curl and the url you gave and it doesn't return anything.

Comment: This comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/66334113/671013 helped me to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

Could reproduce the problem and also run into an "endless" loading. Do not know why, but you may try the following:

**Scraping Website**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
URL = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/tsla'

driver.get(URL)
driver.implicitly_wait(3) 
name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.symbol-page-header__name').text
print(name)
driver.close()
```

**"Scraping API"**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import json

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
URL = 'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/tsla/company-profile'

driver.get(URL)

jsonResponse = json.loads(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('pre').text)
print(jsonResponse['data'].get('CompanyName'))
driver.close()
```

**Direct use of API**

https://dataondemand.nasdaq.com/docs/?python#