# Can't find hyper link for this csv file on website

Tags: python

In this NASDAQ website below, there is a button "Download CSV", however there is no hyperlink for it when I right click on that button. Can you help to find a way to download using Python?

https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener

Comment: When you click that link, a temporary file is created and its download initiated - there isn't a pre-existing link you can reliably download to get that .csv. One way to do it (easy, but not very effecient) would be to use `selenium` and just 'click the button' from you script in a headless browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Download CSV button isn't a link to a file. It is Javascript which is fetching the data from api.nasdaq.com in JSON format, converting it to CSV in memory, and loading the resource as a link with data:text/csv so your browser downloads it.

If you are using Chrome, open the Dev Tools by pressing F12 key on keyboard, and go to the Network tab. Then click the Download CSV button and watch the requests. You will see https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&limit=25&offset=0&download=true which is fetching the data you want but in JSON format.

In python you can do a GET request with that URL.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_get.asp

Load the response as JSON. Then convert to CSV. Here is JSON to CSV example.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-json-to-csv-in-python/

**Update**

It seems their API is a little picky. Try this to fetch the data:

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.nasdaq.com")
payload = ''
headers = {'Cookie': ''}
conn.request("GET", "/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&limit=25&offset=0&download=true", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: This code doesn't return any status code after 10 minutes ```import requests
x = requests.get('https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&limit=25&offset=0&download=true')
print(x.status_code)```

Comment: See my update above.

Comment: It works correctly! Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler `requests`-based answer. The nasdaq.api has measures in place to prevent web scraping. You need to set additional header information to be able to access the data as answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66334113/5755604)

```
import requests
url = "https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&limit=25&offset=0&download=true"
headers = {"Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.9",
"Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
"User-Agent":"Java-http-client/"}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
json = response.json()
```